# android system tries to draw large size bitmap (Crash report)

Tags: android, view, bitmap, crash, crash-reports

In the Developer Console I get following Crash Report. I really don't know where the issue is. Here is my GitHub link to this project: https://github.com/DaFaack/Mr.Politik

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
  at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1420)
  at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:545)
  at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1286)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18318)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17296)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18080)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17291)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18080)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17291)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18080)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17291)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18080)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18321)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:919)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17296)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:692)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:698)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:806)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3128)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2924)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2516)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1515)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7091)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:638)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

What does this error message mean and how can I solve it?

Comment: How big is the bitmap?  It probably means OOM

Answer (score 0):

[From source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/DisplayListCanvas.java#256):

```
protected void throwIfCannotDraw(Bitmap bitmap) {
    super.throwIfCannotDraw(bitmap);
    int bitmapSize = bitmap.getByteCount();
    if (bitmapSize > MAX_BITMAP_SIZE) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "Canvas: trying to draw too large(" + bitmapSize + "bytes) bitmap.");
    }
}
```

And defined at the top of the file:

```
private static final int MAX_BITMAP_SIZE = 100 * 1024 * 1024; // 100 MB
```

As to where, in your source the error is being thrown? I know even less then you - based on what has been posted. Try finding places you might be drawing large images, and validate they are not larger then 100MB.

Answer (score 0):

That's a looks wierd. Put your all .jpg and .png files to drawable-nodpi folder inside res folder. What is the occurance rate of bug and devices that has that crash please

Comment: This Crash only appears in Android Version 7